# Using the moongoose find() method to query items within arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is what my schema's look like.

```
const CollectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  since: Date,
  batch_id: Number,
  info: [InfoSchema],
  items: [ItemSchema]
});

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  url: String
});
```

I'm looking for Collection batch_id, Collection info, Item price, Item url for a particular item name. Please note that a Collection has an array of Items, and we can assume the Item Names are distinct. Below query (i think) should return Collection info + batch_id for collections that have any item with the name 'lego'.

```
Collections.find(
  { "items.name": 'lego' },
  { info: 1, batch_id: 1 }
)
   .where("since")
   .gt(minutesAgo)
```

**I would like to include Item price and Item url in the response**. How would i change the find() call to return that data? Again, adding items: 1 will add all the items (but i'm looking for the price and url only for the matched Item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return just the selected item with [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation), but unfortunately in that case you cannot select which fields of the item to return (you would need to use aggregation framework for that):

```
Collections.find(
  { "items.name": "lego" },
  { info: 1, batch_id: 1, "items.$": 1 }
)
```

> The query above will return only the FIRST matching item, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `items.price` and `items.url` into the select query to include the missing fields.

```js
Collections.find(
  { "items.name": 'lego' },
  { info: 1, batch_id: 1, "items.price": 1, "items.url": 1 }
)
   .where("since")
   .gt(minutesAgo)
```

Comment: This returns the price and url for every item in the collection (and not only the selected one).